# Register this connection's addresses in DNS in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, vpn

I need a way to programatically (powershell, batch, c#, ...) tell my VPN adapter that it has to register address in DNS.

There seems to be no parameter for this using PowerShell to create the VPN entry:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command Add-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection -Name "ProfileName" -ServerAddress "xyz.com" -TunnelType L2tp -EncryptionLevel Optional -L2tpPsk "password" -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -Force
```

We had no success doing this by [GPO](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6700ebff-aad5-415b-844c-71574a103ac1/advanced-tcpip-settings-with-dns-and-vpn-register-this-connection-address-with-dns?forum=winserveripamdhcpdns), netsh or c# (DotRas -> `VpnEntry.Options.RegisterIPWithDns = true;`)

[image: screenshot of the Windows Setting]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are no way of doing it with the Add-VpnConnection command.

Instead you have to edit the Remote Access Phonebook.

If it is a `-alluserconnection` VPN the phonebook can be found here: 
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk`

If it is a per user VPN adapter the phonebook can be found here: 
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk`

Now use this Powershell command to set the setting:

```
$RASPhoneBook = 
“C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk”
(Get-Content $RASPhoneBook) -Replace ‘IpDnsFlags=0’, ‘IpDnsFlags=3’ | 
Set-Content $RASPhoneBook
```

“Register this connection’s addresses in DNS” is now set for your VPN adapter.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Be sure to format code snippets as code so they easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | where {$_.some.identifying.vpn.feature -eq 'name'} | Get-NetConnectionProfile | Set-DnsClient -RegisterThisConnectionsAddress:$True
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also doesn't work. Get-NetIPConfiguration only lists WLAN, Bluetooth, Ethernet and celluar interfaces but seems to ignore the VPN connection / adapter.

Comment: Interesting, I've tried both Cisco AnyConnect, as well as SonicWALL NetExtender, and both of them show up with Get-NetIPConfiguration

Comment: Well, my VPN is just a normal Windows VPN adapter which doesn't get listed with these commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a different approach for your use case.
Example:

[Using PowerShell to Get or Set NetworkAdapterConfiguration-View and Change Network Settings Including DHCP, DNS, IP Address and More (Dynamic AND Static) Step-By-Step](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/01/31/using-powershell-to-get-or-set-networkadapterconfiguration-view-and-change-network-settings-including-dhcp-dns-ip-address-and-more-dynamic-and-static-step-by-step.aspx)

Following commands can be useful to configure the settings:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName . | Select-Object -Property [a-z]* -ExcludeProperty IPX*,WINS*

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "FullDNSRegistrationEnabled=true" –ComputerName . | Get-Member

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled=true" –ComputerName . | Get-Member
```

Comment: Thanks, but these commands seem to ignore the VPN adapter. They only list the ip of Wifi, LAN, Bluetooth and celluar. It seems like VPN is not a Win32_Networkadapter.